# How to change the text color of a transparent header on scroll, depending on the div it overlaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, each

I have a header with a transparent backgrounsd, and I am trying to get the text of the header to change colour between white and black depending on the background of the div it's overlapping.

So far I have managed to add a class of `.color-menu` to all the divs where I want the header to be black.

I then have it add a class of `.dark-menu` to the header when the `.color-menu` div reaches the top of the page.

The problem is that it only works for the first .colour-menu div. It will change to black when it is in the viewport and back to white for the next div but then when the next .color-menu div gets to the top it doesn't change.

So, it seems like the `.each` function isn't working but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 $('.color-menu').each(function(i){
  var top_of_element = $(".color-menu").offset().top;
  var bottom_of_element = $(".color-menu").offset().top + $(".color-menu").outerHeight();
  var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

  if ((top_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)) {
    $(".header").addClass("dark-menu");
  } else {
    $(".header").removeClass("dark-menu");
  }
 });
});
```

UPDATE: I have also tried using $(this) but it really throws off when it changes color.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 $('.color-menu').each(function(i){
  var top_of_element = $(this).offset().top;
  var bottom_of_element = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
  var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

  if ((top_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)) {
    $(".header").addClass("dark-menu");
  } else {
    $(".header").removeClass("dark-menu");
  }
});
});
```

Here is a simplified version of my code as an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".white").addClass("color-menu");
  $(".white-bold").addClass("color-menu");
  $(".light").addClass("color-menu");
  $(".light-bold").addClass("color-menu");
  $(".bright").addClass("color-menu");
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.color-menu').each(function(i){
    var top_of_element = $(".color-menu").offset().top;
    var bottom_of_element = $(".color-menu").offset().top + $(".color-menu").outerHeight();
    var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

    if ((top_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)) {
      $(".header").addClass("dark-menu");
    } else {
      $(".header").removeClass("dark-menu");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  margin: 0;
  padding:10px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
.header a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.dark-menu a{
  color: black;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
}
.white, .white-bold, .light, .light-bold, .bright {
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <a>This is the header</a>
</div>
<div class ="black"></div>
<div class ="white"></div>
<div class ="black"></div>
<div class ="white-bold"></div>
<div class ="black"></div>
<div class ="light"></div>
<div class ="black"></div>
<div class ="light-bold"></div>
<div class ="black"></div>
<div class ="bright"></div>
```

Comment: Can you create a [MRE] with an example of the HTML that shows the problem? It would make it easier to help when we can see what is happening :)

Comment: Here is a simplified codepen of the effect I am going for. You will notice that it changes between black and white for the first bit but then doesn't continue for the next sections. https://codepen.io/rbunz08/pen/eYzYWdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening in your code is that on scroll, you loop through every `color-menu` div and add the class if it is the current one... but then the code *continues* to loop though the remaining elements in the array and removes it again because the page is not in the other div.

I've explained step-by-step the changes you need to get this to work after the example, but first you can see it working here:

**Working Example**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".white").addClass("color-menu");
  $(".white-bold").addClass("color-menu");
  $(".light").addClass("color-menu");
  $(".light-bold").addClass("color-menu");
  $(".bright").addClass("color-menu");

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var inColorMenu = false;            /* initialise var to store if we are in color-menu */
    var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();          /* just get this once outside loop */

    /* Loop through each color-menu element and check if we are in one */
    $('.color-menu').each(function(i) {
      var top_of_element = $(this).offset().top;
      var bottom_of_element = top_of_element + $(this).outerHeight();

      /* if we are in a color-menu element, set our var to true and stop processing */
      if ((top_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)) {
        inColorMenu = true;
        return false;         /* N.B. need to return "false" to break from the "each" loop */
      }
    });

    if (inColorMenu) {
      $(".header").addClass("dark-menu");
    } else {
      $(".header").removeClass("dark-menu");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

.header a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header.dark-menu a {
  color: black;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
}

.white,
.white-bold,
.light,
.light-bold,
.bright {
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <a>This is the header</a>
</div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="white-bold"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="light-bold"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="bright"></div>
```

**How this works:**

1. Declare a variable to record whether we are in a "color-menu" class or not, and initialise this to false, e.g.:

```
var inColorMenu = false;
```

---

2. When looping through `$('.color-menu').each`, if we are between the top and bottom of one of divs (which your code is already detecting), then set our variable to true to record this.
   We can also return `false` to break the `each` loop and stop processing the rest of the elements (it will still work without this, we are just reducing the amount of processing required):

```
if ((top_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)) {
    inColorMenu = true;
    return false;         /* N.B. need to return "false" to break from the "each" loop */
}
```

---

3. Finally, after we finish our `$('.color-menu').each` loop, if `inColorMenu` is true, we know we are in a `color-menu` div so we add the `dark-menu` class to the header, otherwise we remove it:

```
if (inColorMenu) {
    $(".header").addClass("dark-menu");
} else {
    $(".header").removeClass("dark-menu");
}
```

---

4. Note: You need to use `$(this)` when getting the `offset().top` and `outerHeight()` so that you are getting the values for the *current* element in the loop. `$(".color-menu")` gets the values for an unspecified element with this class so will not work.

Comment: Thank you sooo much!!! This was a great help. Thank you for taking the time to explain it as well!

Comment: @RebeccaB Glad to help! This was only a simplified version of your code, so I explained the changes in detail so that you'd understand the changes needed when you come to make them in your project :)